# Iniciar aplicacion node al iniciar contenedor Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Estoy aprendiendo un poco de Docker y hasta ahora mejor de lo que pense, solo encontre un pequeño problema el cual no logro resolver.

ya tengo mi imagen con todos los requisitos para correr un sistemita en nodejs el cual cuenta de 2 partes el frontend y el backend.

De momento solo logro correrlos en conjunto y solamente si corro los comandos de start manualmente desde la consola.

Mi archivo yml:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  soporte:
    build:
      context: './soporte/'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "8080:8080"
    container_name: soporte
```

Mi archivo DockerFile se el siguiente:

```
FROM imagensoportep

RUN mkdir -p /home/soporte

COPY soporte /home/soporte

WORKDIR /home/soporte/backend

RUN cd /home/soporte/backend

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

RUN npm install -g pm2

RUN pm2 start dist/server.js --name soporte-backend

WORKDIR /home/soporte/frontend

RUN cd /home/soporte/frontend

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

RUN pm2 start server.js --name soporte-frontend

RUN pm2 save

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 8080
```